# Is the function ${e^{-{1}\over{x}}}\over {x}$ on $(0,1)$ uniformly continuous or bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

$$f(x)= {{e^{-{1}\over{x}}}\over {x}}$$  for  $x\in (0,1)$  .

Is  this  function

$a$) uniformly  continuous

$b$) bounded  but not  continuous

$c$) unbounded

This  would  be   uniformly  continuous  if  $f$  could  be  defined  continuously  on $0$  and  $1$.  But  that  does  not  look  possible.

Help.

Comment: "This would be uniformly continuous if f could be defined continuously on 0 and 1. But that does not look possible." Why do you say that?

Comment: Substitute $u=1/x$.

Comment: @zhw. Why  do  I  say  what ? Why  it  looks  not  possible  or  why  it   would  be  uniformly  continuous  if  extended  continuously  at  $0$  and  $1$ $?$

Comment: Why it looks not possible.

Comment: @Urgje : Then  it  becomes  $u e^{-u}$. Now  limit $x \rightarrow 0$  implies  $u\rightarrow {\infty} $ .  Then  $e^{-u} \rightarrow  0$ ,  but  will  that  mean  $u e^{-u} \rightarrow 0$ .  A  little  confused  here  as  in  the  product  $u$  does  tend  to  $0$.

Comment: The exponential tales care of this: $ue^{-u}=u/{e^u}$

Comment: @Urgie : Thanks .Then  goes  to  $0$  at  $0$  since  exponential  increases  faster  than  identity .  Am  I  right?

Comment: This is indeed the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking  clue  from urgie's  comments **:**

${e^{-1\over x}}\over x$  is  continuous  on  $(0,1)$ . This will be  uniformly  continuous  if  it  can be extended continually  to $[0,1]$ . Now extending it to $(0,1]$ is no problem . Problem is at the point $0$. Put $u={{1\over x}}$  in the function . Then we have , $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{e^{-1\over x}}\over x }\\=\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty} u\cdot e^{-u}\\=0$$ as $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0} e^{-u}=0$  and $e^u\gt\gt u$  implies the product with $u$ will  certainly  go to $0.$ So defining $f(0)=0$ will  serve  the  purpose. Thus  $f$ is uniformly continuous.

And of course  *bounded.*